# Changing package name causes errors even tho done correctly

Tags: eclipse, github, java-ee-8

**Hello,**

I have been modifying a project i imported from github **just for personal use**, A web application in java ee using eclipse.

So i wanted to change the parent package name to something like 'com' instead of 'johnny' using the refractor>rename command with preconditions selected

as you see in the screenshot below :

[image: package name]

but whenever i do so it turns out like this :

[image: package name 2]

After i run the web application i start getting exceptions and errors all over the place.

**Here is a stack trace for one of the exceptions i have got :**

```
Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:626)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:515)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Root Cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
johnny.gamestore.mysql.dao.ProductDao.getProductList(ProductDao.java:33)
johnny.gamestore.mysql.dao.ProductDao.searchProduct(ProductDao.java:70)
org.apache.jsp.searchproduct_jsp._jspService(searchproduct_jsp.java:182)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

When i rename the package back to its original name 'johnny' the application works fine and the black * icon is gone and replaced with a yellow shield icon i think.

I made sure to rename the package right no errors in the code but still gives me trouble when renaming.

Does anyone have an idea of what is happening ? Much appreciated

Comment: Search for the original package name. You may have missed a configuration file (non Java file), or somewhere reflection is used.

Comment: i was trying to do that, i have looked in every file in the project but i feel like i am missing something , even the database structure checked it but the original package name is nowhere to be found, any ideas on where exactly to look ?